# Resizing element dynamically, but maintaining proportion of its background

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container which houses 4 elements on each line. They proportionally change size dynamically, however they have a **multi-sprite background image** (which does not rotate in this demonstration).

[image]

I set the width of my container to **23.75%**, what do I set as my height so that the (small portion) of my background image is always proportional?

```
.body {
    margin: 15px;
    background: grey;
}
.container {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/MUQ1HxQ.jpg"); 
    background-size: 600% 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 23.75%;
    height: 15vw;
    display: inline-block;
}
.body .container:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mfp3ngg/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the solution I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/53cpq57q/1/) (css+Jquery)

```
.body {
    margin: 15px;
    background: grey;
}
.container {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/MUQ1HxQ.jpg"); 
    background-size: 600% 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 23.75%;
    height: 15vw;
    display: inline-block;
}
.body .container:nth-child(4n+1) {
    margin-left: 1%;
}
```

---

```
<div class="body">

<div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div><div class="container"></div>

</div>
```

---

```
$(window).ready(updateHeight);
$(window).resize(updateHeight);

function updateHeight()
{
    var div = $('.container');
    var width = div.width() * 0.56;

    div.css('height', width);
}
```